# Highlight cells based on 10-15 values and post alternatives

Tags: excel, excel-formula, highlighting, conditional-formatting

I have a 1600-2000 rows of data in a spreadsheet that changes daily. I would like to highlight any row that contains such as `000000000000053851` in the R column. I had tried conditional formatting using this formula:

> =OR($R1="000000000000549543",$R1="000000000000267294,$R1="000000000000053851")

but it seems to highlight a few rows that are blank in column R also.

Using the same numbers highlighted in column R, I would like to have an alternate number and possibly other data pasted into the corresponding row in column S. Each number has a unique alternate number and data to go along with it. This is how I picture a line may look with the highlighting and alternate data next to it:

[image: an example how I picture it looking]

I intend to record a macro using a few of the different steps that are likely required to do this. Any way, whether conditional formatting or an array formula, would be great to help with this.

Comment: If you put your "numbers of interest" in a separate range you can use `NOT(ISERROR(MATCH()))` in your CF formula.  Second part of your question is unclear, but possibly you could use `VLOOKUP` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample provided, a CF rule of:

```
=LEFT(R1,12)="000000000000"
```

applied to ColumnR will format the sample and if you wish the cell immediately to the right. It will not highlight blank cells.

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**, enter formula from above and <kbd>Format...</kbd> with Fill red, OK, OK.

If you want the cell to the right to be formatted also, select ColumnsR:S instead of just ColumnR and change `R1` in the formula to `$R1`.

For the cell to the right you provide few details but [VLOOKUP](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/) in conjunction with a two-column table should suit. Column on the left being the ColumnR value, with the right-hand column for the same row the ColumnS value required. This table could be placed almost anywhere.

This could all be done with Record Macro.

Comment: So would I then just have a new rule for each item number I want to highlight or can I string the numbers together in the same formula somehow?

Comment: I am fine with all the different numbers being highlighted by the same color, the highlighting was to quickly spot the specific rows among all the other rows of different data. I expect only 50 or so rows out of the 1600+ to be highlighted.

Comment: The item numbers are 18 digits and started at 000000000000000001 and are currently around 000000000000400000, so currently there is a 12-17 zeroes range per number. I will take a look at your new formula this weekend and let you know how it works.

Comment: I have the conditional formatting and VLOOKUP working properly, the only thing is that I need to paste my table into the spreadhseet at AZ2 before using my recorded macro because I am unable to paste and have it work during the recording of my macro. Is it possible to have a table added with data already entered to each new spreadhseet via a recorded macro? If so I will likely need to enter a new question as this question is probably too long as it is.